# How to send a custom header on every request with an angular resource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, header

I like to send a custom header on every request with an angularjs resource. Before every request the header has to be created again. The following doesn't work. The header is calculated only once and because of this only one request works. A second request on the same resource fails. Its a lot of copy n paste of "headers: authhandler.createHeader()" also ...

```
myApp.service('Rest', ['$resource', 'authhandler',
        function($resource, 'authhandler',{
            return {
                User: $resource( api_domain + "/api/users/:userid", {}, {
                    get: {method: 'GET', headers: authhandler.createHeader()},
                    remove: {method: 'DELETE', headers: authhandler.createHeader()},
                    edit: {method: 'PUT', headers: authhandler.createHeader()},
                    add: {method: 'POST', headers: authhandler.createHeader()},
                    patch: {method: 'PATCH', headers: authhandler.createHeader()}
                }),
            };
        }]);
```

Has someone an idea how to solve this ?
I had a working solution but I don't like it because of huge amount of copy and paste source code:

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function(RestResource, authhandler, $routeParams) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common = authhandler.createHeader();
    RestResource.get({userid: $routeParams.id}, function(result) {
        //...
    });
});
```

I Would be very happy about hints how to solve this ! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you need to configure the `$http` default headers each time, it is a global parameter. Just add it at the beginning of your application, or where it is supposed to change.

Comment: @lechariotdor: Thanks for your reply, but the header has different parameters for each request. So it should be recalculated each time ...

Answer (score 4):

You can use a request transformer:

```
function($resource, 'authhandler',{
   return {
        User: $resource( api_domain + "/api/users/:userid", {}, {
            get: {
                  method: 'GET',
                  transformRequest: function(data, headersGetter) {
                    var currentHeaders = headersGetter();
                    angular.extend(currentHeaders, authhandler.createHeader());
                    return data;
                  }
                },
```

You could also add the transformer to **all** requests:

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(function(data, headersGetter) {
                    var currentHeaders = headersGetter();
                    angular.extend(currentHeaders, authhandler.createHeader());
                    return data;
                  });
```

That way you don't have to configure anything or your resources.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! This solution works :-) But is there a possibility to add this transformRequest method dynamically to all $resource actions ? If not is there a way to avoid copying this method to all my $resource actions ?

Comment: Thank you ! This looks very promising ! At the moment I'm refactoring my code because "authhandler" is currently not a Provider. Only providers can be injected into a config block.

Comment: Do you think putting "$http.defaults.transformRequest.push..." into the "myApp.run" block instead of "myApp.config" block has the same effect ? In run block I can access other services to support creating the header.

Comment: I'm using angular 1.5.7 and it does not work anymore.